# I want resume other thread if one thread fails in execution

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

My sample code is as below:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
List<Callable<Void>> job = new ArrayList<>();
ex.invokeAll(job);
```

I have 3 jobs running in parallel and one job fails it should not revert other jobs. I want it to wait for all jobs to finish ( success or fail) and then update status. Need help in handling this use case

Tried using `afterExecute`

Answer (score 1):

If a job submitted to an executor service fails, it doesn't affect other jobs.

So you only have to wait until jobs finished. The most straightforward way is to get Futures results:

```
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    List<Callable<Void>> job = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Future<Void>> futures = ex.invokeAll(job);

    for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
        try {
            future.get();
            // job succeed
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // job failed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to submit async task to default or specified executor. The benefit of this approach is: then you could use advance compose and exception handling operation per CompletableFuture.

Example with waiting on all with usage of custom executor:

```
    ExecutorService ex = newFixedThreadPool(3);
    List<Callable<Void>> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    jobs.add(() -> {
        System.out.println("Callable 1");
        return null;
    });
    jobs.add(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Callable 2");
        return null;
    });
    jobs.add(() -> {
        System.out.println("Callable 3");
        return null;
    });

    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Callable<Void> job: jobs) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> cp = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                job.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return null;
        }, ex);
        completableFutures.add(cp);
    }

    completableFutures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```